# Clipboard hook to Android's stock web browser

Tags: android, browser, clipboard

Do you know of any way to hook to Android's stock web browser, so that I can select, copy & paste a web page content programmatically?

Comment: Do you want to copy from a WebView in your app or the browser app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected text in stock Android Browser is copied to ClipBoard. Use ClipBoardManager to get the copied text (like below).

```
 ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
 String text = clipboard.hasText() ? clipboard.getText().toString() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
if (clipboardManager.hasText()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Clipboard Text = " + clipboardManager.getText().toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    clipboardManager.setText(null);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "No Content in Clipboard. So set some text in clipboard",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    clipboardManager.setText("AndroidPeople.com");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Clipboard Text = " + clipboardManager.getText().toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```